# Detecting the Enter and Leave of Visual mode event

Tags: vimscript, autocmd, visual-mode, vimscript-lua, events

Are there any events similar to `InsertEnter` and `InsertLeave` that I could use for visual mode?

Looking through the helpfiles, I did not fine any.

If not, how would I be able to detect if Vim enters or leaves Visual mode?

Comment: Maybe duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/q/15561132/11135136.

Comment: I think your suggested question is not a duplicate. The question is related but the implementations are not what I am looking for.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

September of last year, a new event was added:

```
commit f1e8876fa2359b572d262772747405d3616db670 (tag: v8.2.3430)
Author: =?UTF-8?q?Magnus=20Gro=C3=9F?= <magnus.gross@rwth-aachen.de>
Date:   2021-09-12

    patch 8.2.3430: no generic way to trigger an autocommand on mode change

    Problem:    No generic way to trigger an autocommand on mode change.
    Solution:   Add the ModeChanged autocommand event. (Magnus Gross, closes #8856)
```

From [`:h ModeChanged`](https://neovim.io/doc/user/autocmd.html#ModeChanged):

```
ModeChanged         After changing the mode. The pattern is
                    matched against `'old_mode:new_mode'`, for
                    example match against `*:c*` to simulate
                    |CmdlineEnter|.
                    The following values of |v:event| are set:
                            old_mode    The mode before it changed.
                            new_mode    The new mode as also returned
                                        by |mode()| called with a
                                        non-zero argument.
```

So you can use the following event pattern:

```
augroup VisualEvent
  autocmd!
  autocmd ModeChanged *:[vV\x16]* :echom 'VisualEnter'
  autocmd Modechanged [vV\x16]*:* :echom 'VisualLeave'
augroup END
```

`[vV\x16]` is a regex pattern matching either of v (visual mode), V (line-wise), or ctrl-v (block-wise).

---

Answer found courtesy of [clason](https://github.com/clason).

Comment: Thank you for the detailed answer! I will test your code out when I can and get back to you(I only need a day or two).

Comment: Hmm, it appears that your snippet does not detect if visual mode has been left using Escape.

Comment: @UnrealApex detects with <ESC> for me. Maybe not using bang is causing problem. I edited the answer to incorporate augroup. Try that. After entering and leaving visual mode, you should invoke `:messages` to see the messages left with echom.

Comment: My bad, I meant <C-c>. That was a silly thing to ask because I remember that it doesn't trigger `InsertLeave` like <Esc> does. I think your solution shall do. I'll give it a try with Escape.

Comment: @UnrealApex interesting! <C-c> doesn't trigger ModeChanged event. (It wasn't silly. I didn't know about <C-c> not triggering InsertLeave. Your objection made me aware of it.)

Comment: If you find a reason why <C-c> doesn't trigger these events, share here. Or edit my answer with a note.

Comment: I think it is fine, thank you!

Comment: @UnrealApex, kadekai: <C-c> not triggering ModeChanged was a bug. [I finally got around to reporting it weeks after reading your discussion](https://github.com/vim/vim/issues/11394), and Bram fixed it within hours!

Comment: Hooray! Sadly I use Neovim so I do not think the fix will work for me unless someone patches it in the Neovim repository too.

Comment: @UnrealApex [zeertzjq is on it](https://github.com/neovim/neovim/pull/20722). He is a core nvim dev, so patch should be ported quickly.

Comment: I see, hopefully that is the case.

Answer (score 0):

I went ahead and rewrote 3N4N's answer in Lua in case some Neovim users would like to take advantage of this:

```lua
local visual_event_group =
  vim.api.nvim_create_augroup("visual_event", { clear = true })

vim.api.nvim_create_autocmd("ModeChanged", {
  group = visual_event_group,
  pattern = { "*:[vV\x16]*" },
  callback = function()
    print("VisualEnter")
  end,
})

vim.api.nvim_create_autocmd("ModeChanged", {
  group = visual_event_group,
  pattern = { "[vV\x16]*:*" },
  callback = function()
    print("VisualLeave")
  end,
})
```